# Woocommerce Storefront navigation menu active page color change

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

This is my website [graceamaron.com](https://graceamaron.com/)

It was wordpress hosted site.

I have changed the primary navigation menu hover from default to **#4fff51** by the below CSS.

```
.storefront-primary-navigation ul li a:hover {
    color : #4fff51;
}
```

And now I have tried to change active menu color by below code

```
.storefront-primary-navigation ul li a:active {
    color : #4fff51;
}
```

But it's not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: :active pseudo class wont work since you are redirecting when u activate your anchor - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active 
Wordpress adds classes when you are redirected to specific page from menu. Read more about the classes here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/. Also keep in mind that some themes have custom nav walkers which may differ the classes but that is more theme related situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WordPress theme adds the class `current_page_item` to the `li` item that is active. So if you want to change the active page URL color in the nav menu use the following class:

```
.current_page_item a {
    color: red!important;
}
```

See screenshot to see it working.

[image]

Comment: `.current_page_item a:active {
 color : #4fff51;
}` added this code. But doesn't work : (

Comment: Don't use :active, make it: `.current_page_item a { color : #4fff51; }`

Comment: See my updated answer copy that css class into your style.css and change the color to your liking. You need `!important` to overwrite the themes preset color. So in your case it will be `.current_page_item a { color : #4fff51!important; }`

Comment: `.current_page_item a {
 color : #4fff51!important;
}
 `  this only works ..  Thank you so much @FUZIION

Comment: No problem! Goodluck with your site if you have any other issues I'm happy to help. See my profile for contact information